# Is it OK to use Super User's PageDown toolbar image?

Tags: support, design, images, licensing

We're looking for a better PageDown toolbar than the default OOTB sprite, and like the looks of [the one](http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/Img/wmd-buttons.png) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour):

[image]

Are we allowed to use this same sprite for our site?